# How to prevent Windows to keep history of opened file in javafx?

Tags: javafx

I have a project that read Excel files and Custom extension files (.verify). It is working fine but more than expected.

I have used an Inno Setup 5 to be able to install my Java FX app in Windows and set up some file association.

Everything is ok but now, in the recent tab of the application in Windows, it shows every files i opened from the application like in the screenshoot:[image]

my question is **How to disable this feature from the javafx code?** or at least check for some condition like if the file is an Excel or a Verify file because i dont want to implement an "Open Excel From Outside" behavior.

I've search the question title above on both Google and Stack Overflow before asking that question here but didn't find adequate result...

And for the code i tried, i can't try anything because i dont have any clue for where to start...
My guess was searching in the `FileChooser` class but there doesn't seem to be something about history in there.

Does this problem have a solution?

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/236711/how-to-turn-off-recent-items-and-frequent-places-in-windows-10/

Comment: From the sounds of things, this appears to have nothing to do with JavaFX. If you open any file on Windows, it will show up in your recent list.

Comment: Thank you, i was thinking so too... but since apps like chrome has custom tabs like Tasks, Most Viewed, Recently closed ... i thought there should be a way to handle this from the application